# prestashop database huge volume table ps_search_index

Tags: mysql, prestashop

the ps_search_index table has 10 million rows in database. when i create a backup of database it take more than 100MB. how can i deactivate an option or do a instructions to decrease the capacity of database and this table doesn't take some rows? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reduce that table is disabling the indexing of the fields with a lot of content, like the description and short description of the products.

To achieve this, in the back office go to the **Search** page and set to **0** the field of **Short description weight** and the **Description weight** and save.

And then just need to re-build the entire index.

*PD. After this change you will be excluding searches within the long and short description of your products.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slow down your prestashop, for sure, You need to disable indexing on fields. That is something You should NEVER do. Besides it is not the index that is large, it is the containing data. So you have to live with the fact, You need big tables to having decent searching and indexing speeds up the queries on that data. You can not reduce the size unless Prestashop decides to split that table to several other tables, but still, the total amount of data would be the same.